# How to start contributing for GSoC 16 : Email sending framework?

Tags: gsoc

I am Pulkit Bhatia , a third year Computer Science student from USICT,GGSIPU,DELHI and aspirant for GSoC 2016.I was going through community idea list and I am very much interested and excited in working with Email Sending Framework with civiCRM.

I was responsible for backend development during my previous internship where I developed RESTful API using PHP , CodeIgniter Framework and MySQL database.As idea list says , this project involves cronning/scheduling mail services with more robust library such as PHPMailer etc and supporting external mail services through API or plugins, which supports my interest and my previous experience and thus will certainly help me in extending my knowledge and experience in server coding.I am really excited to be part of this organization.

I have already setup my development environment and  successfully integrated civiCRM with drupal.I also started looking into documentation and experimenting around with it. Assistance regarding Project specifics would be a great help.

I am keenly looking forward to hear from the community and mentors who can guide me to proceed further.

Regards  :)

Comment: Hi and thanks for your interest. Did you already reach to the primary mentor? eg. on irc?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have posted in Civicrm forum but there also i didn't got any reply.No i haven't talked on IRC yet.

Comment: @Xavier, StackExchange is not a good place for discussions and threads, as it is designed for questions that have a single right answer. I'd like to close this thread after you indicate more clearly the right venue/space for GSoC 2016 community introductions, and project discussions, etc.

Comment: @JoeMurray do you have a suggestion for a better place? should we use the forum? (asking that question on meta right now)